# How to keep Element after animation where it is on 100% for permanently - C

Tags: css, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, bootstrap-modal

I am Making modal and its internal content like list needs to be appear from bottom one by one when its open. I manage to make it almost but the problem is I am not getting how to make content hidden or invisible from starting and comes after animation.

[Here is Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavshindeuss/1vxe1L4x/)

Plz, let me know where is mess in css if any or suggest a way.

codes are Bellow on Stacks demand (Snippet is not taking Bootstrap Source Files):

```css
li { transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s; animation-name: list-live; animation-duration: 3s; animation-iteration-count:1; }
li:first-child { animation-delay:100ms; }
li:nth-child(2) { animation-delay:300ms;}
li:nth-child(3) { animation-delay:500ms;}
li:nth-child(4) { transition: transform 1s, opacity 4s; animation-delay: 700ms; }
@keyframes list-live {
 0% { transform: translate(0, 200px); opacity: 0;}
    100% { transform: translate(0, 0); opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li class="tr1">Item 1</li>
            <li class="tr2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="tr3">Item 3</li>
            <li class="tr4">Item 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of making start point where the animation end, you could make it start at the bottom and then transit it to the correct position I guess.

Comment: Or make it two separated animation where the one on opacity doesnt have the delay of the animation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I have edited your css code.

```
li { 
     transition: all .5s; 
     animation:list-live linear 2s forwards;
     opacity: 0;
 }
 .modal-content {
        overflow: hidden; 
 }
li:first-child { animation-delay:100ms; }
li:nth-child(2) { animation-delay:300ms;}
li:nth-child(3) { animation-delay:500ms;}
li:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 700ms; }
@keyframes list-live {
    0% { transform: translateY(200px); opacity: 0;}
    100% { transform: translateY(0); opacity:1;}
}
```